# Saving Inputs with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote the this code, in order to save what I am entering in a entry box to a file where it can be viewed...

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def save(event):
   file = open('HW.txt','w')
   file.write('English:',e+'\n'+'Math:',m+'\n'+'Science:',sci+'\n'+'Spanish:',sp+'\n'+'SS:',ss+'\n'+'WebDev',cp+'\n'+other)
   file.close()
e = Label(root, text="English")
m = Label(root, text="Math")
sci = Label(root, text="Science")
sp = Label(root, text="Spanish")
ss = Label(root, text="Social Studies")
cp = Label(root, text="Computer")
other = Label(root, text="Other")
entry1 = Entry(root)
entry2 = Entry(root)
entry3 = Entry(root)
entry4= Entry(root)
entry5 = Entry(root)
entry6 = Entry(root)
entry7= Entry(root)
e.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
m.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
sci.grid(row=2, sticky=E)
sp.grid(row=3, sticky=E)
ss.grid(row=4, sticky=E)
cp.grid(row=5, sticky=E)
other.grid(row=6, sticky=E)
entry1.grid(row=0,column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1,column=1)
entry3.grid(row=2,column=1)
entry4.grid(row=3,column=1)
entry5.grid(row=4,column=1)
entry6.grid(row=5,column=1)
entry7.grid(row=6,column=1)
s = Button(root, text = "Save")
s.bind("<Button-1>",save)
s.grid(row=7,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

But I am receiving an error on line 5 when the save button is clicked saying...

```
line 5, in save
 file.write('English:',e+'\n'+'Math:',m+'\n'+'Science:',sci+'\n'+'Spanish:',sp+'\n'+'SS:',ss+'\n'+'WebDev',cp+'\n'+other)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Label' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your function. You're trying to call the label of the text instead of the value of the box. This should work better:

```
def save(event):
   file = open('HW.txt','w')
   file.write('English:' + entry1.get() +'\n'+'Math:' + entry2.get() + '\n'+'Science:' + entry3.get() +
              '\n'+'Spanish:' + entry4.get()+'\n'+'SS:' + entry5.get()+'\n'+'WebDev' + entry6.get()+
              '\n'+entry7.get())
```

This returns the value of the box (whatever's inside) as a string and writes it to the file. Also, you had some commas instead of `+`. Every time you add something to a write you need to use a plus sign.

Comment: The difference between commas and pluses is that commas automatically add a space to the end of the string. However, thank you for the reply, and that code works great.

Comment: You know, I can't get that to work on my machine, but if you can manage that, more power to you.

Comment: If the code works, then an accepted answer would be appreciated!